# Finding which side one point is from another point

Tags: mathematics, coordinates, linear-algebra

I have a simple question I think, if point a is to the right of another point I a dirx to be 1, otherwise -1. Likewise for a diry var, if it's above the other point I want it to be -1 otherwise 1. This is what I've worked out so far:

```
dirx = (abs(disx+1)/(disx+1))*-1;
diry = (abs(disy+1)/(disy+1))*-1;
```

The disx and disy are the distance from each other on x and y. I have a +1 to keep from having a division by 0 error, lastly I'm *-1 it all so that it'll match the coordinate system of the game screen where something higher has a lesser value than something lower.

My problem is that I'm still getting a division by 0 error with this code, I'm not sure why as I even added +1 to make sure it wasn't possible???

Comment: I'm having trouble following, a picture would help?

Comment: Actually, the title implies something different than the actual question here... finding which side one vector is from another vector can be done using the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) but your question is about points, not vectors...

Answer (score 2):

if disX = -1, then you'll always get a divide by zero error using that code.

If you're programming in a c-based language, just use the ? operator, a la:

```
if(disX == 0)
{  
  dirX = 0;  
}
else
{  
  dirx = (disX > 0) ? 1 : -1;  
}
```

Comment: there just is one minor bug in your code, it returns -1 if disX==0. but we know 0 has no sign, it's neither positive nor negetive!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how Isaiah wanted to handle 0. I'll put a disclaimer in.

Comment: This code is now identical to `signum` or `sign` which is a standard function in many languages. (Albeit not C/C++.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you just wanted to normalize a vector.

let me break your question into 3 parts :

1. why do you get division by zero?
   it's simply because either `disx` or `disy` values could be exactly (-1). in that situation you computer will start computing `(abs(-1+1)/(-1+1))*-1` which is basically `(0/0)*-1`!
2. how to find sign of a number (or how to normalize 1D vector)?
   let's say you have a number 'X' and you want to check if this number is negative or positive. usually there is a function in math libraries named `sign` or `sgn`. They implement that function like this:

   ```
   int sign(int x)
   {
       if (x > 0)
           return 1;
           else
           if (x < 0)
               return -1;
           else
               return 0;
   }
   ```

   note that there is one extra condition where X is exactly zero, in that case sign function **should** return 0 since x doesn't have any sign!
3. how to normalize a 2D Vector (or a vector in higher dimensions)?
   the basic idea is to create a vector which has a length of exactly 1 so the first step is to calculate length of current vector.

   ```
   length = sqrt(vec.x^2 + vec.y^2 + vec.z^2 + ...)
   ```

   the next step is to shorten (or stretch) your vector so that it's total length equals to exactly 1. and here is how it's done:

   ```
   vec.x = vec.x / length;
   vec.y = vec.y / length;
   vec.z = vec.z / length;
   .
   .
   .
   ```

again note that length is always some positive value but it can be equal to zero (where all elements in your vector are exactly zero). you have to check if a vector's length is zero you can't compute a normalized vector!

Comment: I believe what he's trying to do is return -1 if it's to the left, +1 if it's to the right. This is quite different to normalisation.

Comment: @jordaan: that's exactly second part of my answer, and it's a normalization of 1D vector!

Comment: Ah of course. Sorry, must've had a brain spasm. Forgot that -1 is a normalised 1D :S

Comment: why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Cross Product of the two points and check if it is bigger or smaller than zero (zero means it is on the same line):

Point a
Point b

cp = a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x;

For example:

a= (2,5);
b= (3,4)
cp = 2*4 - 5*3 = 8 - 15 = -7

as cp < 0 the point a is on the left of point b

Your function can thus just do this to return -1 or 1:

```
cp = a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x;
if(cp<0)
   return -1;
else
   return 1;
```

Comment: BTW, if you just have a grid (points cant be 'anywhere') do 'if dirx < 0 return(-1)  else return(1)'